# Matching the last two html 'class' attributes encounter before a variable in Python Regex

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

Regex is definitely giving me a headache. Every time I am moving one step ahead, I have a feeling that I stepping twice back! 
I am trying to extract the class attribute of the last tag before the one containing any first name.

I randomly found that [website](https://boissy-saint-leger.coteparticuliers.com/) which I thought would be a good example to practice. I am trying to write a general rule! Nothing specifically applied to that website. 
The only assumption is that I know what the first name is and that it is contained in a tag (div, span, h1, ...) with a certain class.
Here is my regex trials:

```
re.findall(r'(?:class="(.+)".+){2}.*' + val, source) #'source' is the source code of the page
re.findall(r'(?:class="(.+)".*class=)+' + val, source) #'val' a name that I know is in the page
```

Any explanations on what is wrong or on what to do to succeed in my task would be highly appreciated !
Thanks a lot and stay safe.

Comment: Use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse html

Comment: Unless you’re just using regex as a way to practice/learn, you should use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: @PedroLobito, I also use beautifulsoup but your answert doesnt help much if you dont explain how to perform the task. thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @AMC, I use a proper html parser. Selenium + Beautiful soup
regex doesnt work on prettify soup for your information

Comment: @ThomasAMET _regex doesnt work on prettify soup_ What do you mean? _Selenium + Beautiful soup_ Oh, are both necessary? Also, can you clarify the operation you're trying to perform? You're looking for the last two class attributes (with a value?) before a string appears? It can be any string? What happens if the string is part of the class attribute?

Comment: @AMC yes, both are necessary because depending on the task, I use one or the other.
Python throws an error when I perform regex on a soup object with prettify method applied to it.

About the task I am trying to perform, I believed my question was clear enough, sorry if it's not.
Let me rephrase: given a value (in this case, that will be the first name of an employee on the page I shared), I want to find the class of the tag containing that employee's name as well as the class of the closest tag before (the closest tag having a class attribute).

Comment: @ThomasAMET _Python throws an error when I perform regex on a soup object with prettify method applied to it._ What error? _Let me rephrase: given a value (in this case, that will be the first name of an employee on the page I shared), I want to find the class of the tag containing that employee's name as well as the class of the closest tag before (the closest tag having a class attribute)._ Do you need/want to use regex for this, or are you open to different solutions?

Comment: @AMC I open to any solution but I would prefere using regex and/or selenium/beautifulsoup

Comment: Are you familiar with XPath? I think a nice selenium + xpath solution is possible here.

Comment: @AMC I know xpath and I am using it. Tried to look a solution using it but did not find anything. If you know a xpath that can do the job, please share it

Comment: Edit: after your comment, I continue searching for xpath method that would help to achieve my objective and I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found. Assuming any keyword, you want to retrieve the text of the preceding element.

First find the class of the tag containing your keyword:

```
elt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(keyword))
keyword_class = elt.get_attribute('class')
```

Next you can find the parent or precedingsiblings using xpath.

```
# Find the class of firstnames preceding siblings and access their text
xpath = "//*[@class='{}']//preceding-sibling::*".format(class_name)
pre_siblings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
for sibling in pre_siblings:
   print(sibling.text)
```